# Specific column for each row in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to specific column number for each row like below. `d` is a data like `(embedding_id x n_vocab)` and `t` is a list of correct embedding_id.

Then, I could create `result` like below. The data is good, but I think this is not smart. How do I create `result` in other smart ways?

```
 t = np.random.randint(10, size=(32,))                                          
 d = np.random.randn(30, 32)                                                    

 result = []                                                                    
 for a,b in zip(d.transpose(), t):                                              
     print(a[b])                                                                
     result.append(a[b]) # I don't think this is good way                                                  
 result = np.array(result).astype(float)                                        
 print(result)                                                                  
 print(result.shape) # (32,).
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [index](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) like so; Use `numpy.arrange` to create the column indices and use it with `t` (this is called advanced indexing):

```
d[t, np.arange(len(t))]
```

---

```
(d[t, np.arange(len(t))] == result).all()
# True
```

Comment: That's great. To be sure, the first element `t` is a specific column number and the second one is specific row. So what i want to do is extract value at specific column for every row. I will accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Except I'd say `t` is the row indices while the second one column indices by convention.